# how to get individual count row and store in a place from the multiple id using sql query in c#.net

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am doing one task in that student want to give exam with equally question ratio from their multiple chapters.

So, my logic is that first of all I am getting data of outofmark and totalquestion from their subject. After that I want to divide that two field and get ratio it. After that, the ratio will be divided to the total question from the individual chapter and get the equal question from it.

Let for more clear we will take a ex i.e. :

There is one subject named `Maths`.

Now, in maths there is four chapter.

```
chapter 1 containing 50 question
chapter 2 containing 60 question
chapter 3 containing 40 question and 
chapter 4 containing 30 question.
```

So, total question is 180 (by doing sum of it.)

Let, exam is for 50 marks. [it means 50 question we want one question one mark]

Now, for getting equally ratio of question we will divide `total question to out of marks` i.e. `180 / 50 = 3.5`

Now, 3.5 is the ratio of the 180 question so that we will divide 3.5 from total question from the individual chapter so from that we will know that from individual chapter how many question will come i.e.

from chapter 1 it containing 50 quesiton i.e. `50 / 3.5 = 14.28 => 14 (roundfig)`
and so on by divide the question from the ratio of question we will get the value i.e.

```
chap 1 : 14
chap 2 : 17
chap 3 : 11
chap 4 : 9
Tot Que : 50
```

So, this thing I want to do in c#.net application.

I have tried and some what success also but I am getting issue from divide total question from the individual chapter to the ratio of the question. Here is my code

```
string qryCountQuestion = "Select Count(appQueID) as TotalQuestion, (select appSubMarks from tblSubjectMaster where appSubID = " + cmb_subject.SelectedValue + ") as OutOfQuestion from tblQuestion where appQueSubID = " + cmb_subject.SelectedValue + "";
DataTable dtCountQuestion = new DataTable();
dtCountQuestion = clsObjDataAccess.GetDataTable(qryCountQuestion);
if (dtCountQuestion.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    countQuestion = Convert.ToInt32(dtCountQuestion.Rows[0]["TotalQuestion"]);
    outOfQuestionMark = Convert.ToInt32(dtCountQuestion.Rows[0]["OutOfQuestion"]);
}
```

Now, in this query I am getting the

```
countquestion i.e. 180 and
```

`outofquestion i.e. 50` data related to their subjectId and its working also.

Now, after that I want value of ratio question from which is divided the countquestion from outofquestionmark. And here is the code

```
double ratioOfQuestion = Convert.ToDouble(countQuestion / outOfQuestionMark);
```

Now, I want to divide this ratioOfQuestion to total question from their individual chapter and store it. But here I stuck it. And dont know that how I want to do from the sql query or any other thing.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't tell about the error, but your definition of qryCountQuestion  variable is asking for an SQL injection.. Use instead SqlParameter class.

Comment: I am not getting any type of error. I want some hints that how can I get the total question of individual chapter and divide that question from the ratio and store in some place from the sql query or any other thing.

Comment: You want to calculate the ratio in the sql statement? You can declare a variable and use a stored procedure if you want to take the logic out of code.

Comment: @YaWang Placing logic in database is a bad practice, you should use a business model and keep the logic there..

Comment: can any one show me in code...so that I can implement in my code